# Setting a cookie for user to stay logged in

Tags: php, cookies

so, I am struggling for 1 week now on this PHP code and still can't get it working. I need a cookie to be set for a user for 1 year, and also when he close his browser and visit our site again later, not to have to log in again. If someone can write the code as it should be set on my file I would be very grateful. My original code is bellow, it's from my config.php file.
Many thanks in advance!

```
function create_slrememberme() {
        $key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        global $conn;
        $sql="update members set remember_me_time='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', remember_me_key='".$key."' WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[USERNAME])."'";
        $conn->execute($sql);
        setcookie('slrememberme', gzcompress(serialize(array($_SESSION[USERNAME], $key)), 9), time()+60*60*24*30);
}

function destroy_slrememberme($username) {
        if (strlen($username) > 0) {
                global $conn;
                $sql="update members set remember_me_time=NULL, remember_me_key=NULL WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
                $conn->execute($sql);
        }
        setcookie ("slrememberme", "", time() - 3600);
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["USERNAME"]) && isset($_COOKIE['slrememberme'])) 
{
        $sql="update members set remember_me_time=NULL and remember_me_key=NULL WHERE remember_me_time<'".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y")))."'";
        $conn->execute($sql);
        list($username, $key) = @unserialize(gzuncompress(stripslashes($_COOKIE['slrememberme'])));
        if (strlen($username) > 0 && strlen($key) > 0)
        {
            $sql="SELECT status,USERID,email,username,verified from members WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' and remember_me_key='".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'";
            $rs=$conn->execute($sql);
            if($rs->recordcount()<1)
            {
                $error = "Error: Could not locate your account.";
            }
            elseif($rs->fields['status'] == "0")
            {
                $error = "Error: Your account has been disabled by the administrator.";
            }
            if($error=="")
            {               
                $_SESSION['USERID']=$rs->fields['USERID'];
                $_SESSION['EMAIL']=$rs->fields['email'];
                $_SESSION['USERNAME']=$rs->fields['username'];
                $_SESSION['VERIFIED']=$rs->fields['verified'];
                create_slrememberme();
            }
            else
            {
                destroy_slrememberme($username);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Please do not [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712967/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-for-user-to-stay-logged-in) questions. Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:-

```
setcookie ("slrememberme", "", time() - 3600);
```

is setting your cookie to expire in the past, i.e. it is already expired!

To set it for a year you need to do:-

```
setcookie("slrememberme", "", time()+60*60*24*30*365);
```

will set it for approximately 1 year.

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/setcookie) for more details.

Also, this line:-

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["USERNAME"]) && isset($_COOKIE['slrememberme']))
```

Should be:-

```
if (isset($_SESSION["USERNAME"]) && isset($_COOKIE['slrememberme']))
```

You probably need to set the cookie-expiry function located in your php.ini file named `session.cookie_lifetime`. You should set it to be 31536000, this will make it expire after 1 year, it is probably set to 0.

Comment: Thanks @vascowhite, unfortunately it didn't fix it. Right after I close my browser and go back to the site I am no longer logged in. There is no 'Remember me' box, it is a Facebook Connect button only. Should I put something else to the code into my config.php file? Thanks once again!

Comment: Sorry @vascowhite, I really have no idea what I've done to re-post this question again.
So, this didn't fix it too. I really need this feature enabled, any ideas?

Comment: Dear @vascowhite, I still can't get it working. Have tried to increase the session.gc_maxlifetime to 20000, but still nothing. Desperately need help!

Comment: Dear @vascowhite, I just want to let you know that I fixed it myself :)
I have set the session.cookie_lifetime to 31536000 located in the php.ini file. I hope this will help someone else who struggled like me.
Please excuse me again for the re-post I made, I am new to this community, everyone can make a mistake, this will be my last one. Sorry I can't give you 1 up as I don't have the reputation to do that. Be sure I will as soon as I have 15 reputation points.

Comment: @pafs Thanks for the update, I'm glad you got it sorted out. If you wish you could edit my answer to include your final solution, that way it will be easier to find for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie('usuario-logado', 'true', (time() + ( 24 * 3600)));
```

Comment: you might want to include more details about that code. posting the code with no explanation won't help the OP very much